# Почему романы называют готическими?

Tags: этимология

Романы ужасов о вампирах и прочей нечисти называют готическими. А почему? Есть готическая (стрельчатая) архитектура, название, как я понимаю, связано с готами. А при чем тут вампиры?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Готический роман  получил свое название в связи с особым интересом его авторов к «готике» Средневековья, как они ее понимали, то есть к представлению о мире как арене извечного борения противостоящих начал — добра и зла,  Бога и дьявола, а также потому, что действие готических романов разворачивается, как правило, в средневековых готических замках, церквях, монастырях и т.д., что придает повествованию особый загадочный колорит.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то романы скорее всего - "готичные". Как и многое другое.
"Готично" - словечко бывшее новомодным лет пять назад, аккурат до "гломура". 
Значение - связанный с "готикой", "готами". И еще отдаленный синоним для "романтично", "мистично", "модно" и т.д., а также - "брутально" (последнее - от исторического значения, фиксируемого даже академическими словарями).
Этимология - видимо от "готов", молодежного течения с сильным налетом мистических и эзотерических идей.

**Ларf**, я думаю, что здесь элементарная путаница. Готический роман (Gothic Novel) XVIII века как жанр никто не отменяет. Но те произведения были сродни скорее детективу, нежели современной мистике.

Возможно, я плохо подумал об авторе,  но здесь скорее всего речь идет о современных поделках на темы нечистой силы и загробной жизни.

Впрочем я не специалист. Возможно, авторы современных творений считают себя последователями той школы, тогда естественно роман - готический. Этимологию постараюсь посмотреть, навскидку - она связана как раз с готикой, как стилем архитектуры.

А, Вы уже об этом написали. Хорошо, всё время забываю, что я с дохлым интернетом, не до поисков сейчас.

//---------------------
Нашел, однако

> > Однако, по предположению писательницы Маргарет Дрэббл, термин Gothic изначально употреблялся в значении «средневековый», как в подзаголовке романа «Замок Отранто», действие которого происходит в Средние века (Castle of Otranto, a Gothic Tale)[1].

(С) Вики.  Это более чем похоже. Разумеется - в отношении упомянутых романов XVIII века. Современных, увы, не читал.

Comment: Вряд ли готический роман (возникновение жанра - 18 век) берет свое начало от готов - молодежного течения, которое зародилось в веке двадцатом.

Comment: Эзотерических?

Comment: Ответил в тексте.